# Javascript : Redirecting to another webpage through a popup

Tags: javascript, redirect, popup, sandbox

I'm quite bad with Javascript and I can't work out a solution I need help to. I'm having a website and I'm trying to make a redirection to another site, but through a popup.

Example :

```
<script>alert(This will prompt up the message)</scrip>

<script>window.location="http://This-will-redirect-me-to-another-link.com";</scrip>
```

Like you can see I could simply use the second javascript to redirect the persons to another page, but due some reasons I can't use it as it will work only for half of the page(the script would be kinda 'sandboxed'), but if I'd make a popup(the first alert script) the second script would get out of the 'sandbox'. Is there anyone who has any ideas how I should implement this or can it be done otherwise with PHP or HTML?

---

Thanks for both of your replies yet these doesn't help me out yet although I'm quite sure that your help will. I'm having a MyBB forum and there's a shoutbox for it which I'm using. There's a command which will change the notice of the shoutbox and the command is as such /notice New notice  | But I noted that the new notice can be changed with javascript and it'll work such as /notice js code here | Then I thought that what if I would make such a javascript that would redirect people to another webpage. As I'm having such a forum where it's needed to redirect from the main page to another one, I'd like to apply it. Then Staffs could do it in the forum very well, but there's a problem. by adding

/notice window.location="http://This-will-redirect-me-to-another-link.com";
It'll affect only the shoutbox and shoutbox is being redirected to another webpage, but as an alert works for the whole forum I thought maybe I can redirect them to somewhere else with the alert. I want to know is it possible with just one script then Staffs would be able to do it. I know it's a serious security risk & it can be otherwise also, but I'd really like to experiment with it.

I hope someone can help. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use Confim and capture response to redirect. This popup will show two buttons - OK and Cancel.

```
if(confirm("Popup Message")){
   window.location = "your intended destination";
}else {//do nothing. This will fire if cancel is clicked.}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will do it, but what is the trigger that the user is going to perform to make the redirect happen?
I would also say you will be WAY better off to use something like a jQuery dialog than an alert box
In the head of the HTML

```
<script>
function changePage(whereToGo, messageText)
{
    alert(messageText);
    window.location=whereToGo;
}
</script>
```

Then in the HTML itself

```
<script>changePage("http://This-will-redirect-me-to-another-link.com", "The message you want to show");</script>
```

Note the complete of any error checks

OK, then simply try this

```
<script>
alert("Whatever you want to say") && window.location="http://yourwebsitehere.com";
</script>
```

That will perform both actions in a single statement

Comment: Thank you both for the reply, but unfortunally they couldn't help me at the moment. I edited the question with new information and I hope it can help you to help me to make up some solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 function redirectToPage(url) {
// Open a popup window
var popupWindow = window.open(url, "_blank", "width=500,height=500");
// Check if the popup window was successfully opened
if (popupWindow) {
// Delay the redirect by a few seconds (optional)
setTimeout(function() {
// Redirect the main window to the desired URL window.location.href = url;
}, 3000); // 3000 milliseconds = 3 seconds (adjust as needed)
} else {
// If the popup window was blocked, perform a regular redirect 
   window.location.href = url;
}}
// Example usage: redirect to "https://example.com" through a popup
redirectToPage("https://example.com");
```

Comment: Some decent indentation in your code would make it look a lot nicer and make it far easier to read.